# Unwanted position animation in iOS 14 SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

Swift UI animations seem to behave differently regarding to the animation of a View position in its parent frame for iOS 14 versus iOS 13.
My goal in the code snippet below is to **only animate the resizing of the button text**, which should happen on tapping it.
Instead, in iOS 14, the displacement of the button, which is induced by the toggled visibility of an additional View in the VStack, is also being animated.

Identical code produces different outputs in iOS 13 (Xcode 11) and iOS 14 (Xcode 12 beta 6, on macOS 11 beta).
In iOS 14, how can the old behavior be reproduced?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if self.toggle {
                Rectangle().frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.toggle.toggle()
            }){
                Text("Tap me!")
                    .scaleEffect(self.toggle ? 2 : 1)
                    .animation(
                        Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

This is the desired behavior, as in iOS 13
[image: iOS 13 behavior]

This is the unwanted behavior, as in iOS 14
[image: iOS 14 behavior]

Note that, at least for me, the same unwanted behavior occurs not only in a Playground, but also for iOS 14 in Xcode Previews, as well as in the Simulator and on Device (see project files https://github.com/himbeles/PositionAnimationExample):
[image: iOS 14 behavior Xcode Preview]

Comment: I assume it is Playground issue (such things happen with transitions/animations). Works fine with Xcode 12b5 / iOS 14 in Preview & Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hmm, not for me unfortunately, using Xcode 12 beta 6, iOS 14. Neither on device nor simulator.

Comment: It works fine in iOS14 for me as well. I am seeing the desired preview. It must be because you are previewing in the PlaygroundPage .... PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. But for me, it is not related to playgrounds. I have updated the Question to include a screen capture of my code running directly in a fresh XCode 12 beta 6 project, without any playground code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a change in behavior that is visible in iOS 14, macOS Big Sur, and the Swift Playground if you’re using Xcode 12 on macOS Catalina or macOS Big Sur.

You only want the scaling to animate.

A workaround is to change to an explicit animation and use a different `toggle` to control the scaling.  Then wrap the toggling of `scale.toggle` with `withAnimation { }`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    @State var scale = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if self.toggle {
                Rectangle().frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.toggle.toggle()
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5)) {
                    self.scale.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Tap me!")
                    .scaleEffect(self.scale ? 2 : 1)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your workaround works well, thanks again. For me, the animation "misbehavior" in the orginal code happens also in the Simulator and on device, also without the playground code. May I ask you which platform you are compiling from/to? I am using XCode 12 b6 on macOS 11 b6, compiling for iOS 14 (b6 Simulator, b7 on device).

Comment: I see. I’m compiling with Xcode 12b6 on macOS Catalina and my iPhone is running iOS 13.  So this is apparently an iOS 14/mac OS 11 change in behavior, so I am only seeing it in the Playground. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I hope this change is not here to stay. I find the behavior quite counterintuitive, considering the position of a view is typically handled by the parent view and the animation modifier lives within the child view.

Comment: unfortunatelly I still see this behaviour with Xcode 12.4. I tried to use `withAnimation` in `.onAppear()` as workaraound, but that seems to animate the whole parent view's appearance for some reason :/